# Probability of choosing two cards--event probability

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics

Given six cards:
$A♠, J♠, 2♠, A♥, 2♥, 2♦$, you pick one card at random.

Consider two events:

```
         A : the chosen card is an ace

         S : the chosen card is a spade
```

(a) What is the sample space Ω?

(b) Compute the probabilities P(A) and P(S).

(c) Are the events A and S independent?

(d) Can you find any (other?) pair of independent events for the given set of cards?

I am actually not positive of the sample space here but this is what I have:

$P(A)=\frac{2}{6}=\frac{1}{3}$

$P(S)=\frac{3}{6}=\frac{1}{2}$

Then with the event the probability would equal:$\frac{5}{3}$--I know this is wrong because probability and never be greater than zero

Is any of this correct? I can use some help

Comment: probability is NEVER $>1$.

Comment: @AnuragA thanks, where did I go wrong in calculating the event?

Comment: In b), you got the probabilities right, For c), to check for  independence, we check whether $\Pr(A\cap S)=\Pr(A)\Pr(S)$. Looking at the data, we see that $\Pr(A\cap S)=\frac{1}{6}$, which happens to be $\frac{1}{3}\cdot \frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: As to the $\frac{5}{3}$, I do not know how you calculated that, nor what it is meant to be the probability of.

Comment: The sample space is the set of all possible outcomes.  Hence, $\Omega = \{A\spadesuit, J\spadesuit, 2\spadesuit, A\color{red}{\heartsuit}, 2\color{red}{\heartsuit}, 2\color{red}{\diamondsuit}\}$.

Comment: @AndréNicolas Thanks, I thought for an event like this you use this type of formula: $P(A |B) =\frac{ P(A ∩ B)}{P(B)}$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**(a)** As [N. F. Taussig](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/173070/n-f-taussig) pointed:

> The sample space is the set of all possible outcomes. Hence, $\Omega = \{A♠, J♠, 2♠, A♥, 2♥, 2♦ \}$

**(b)** As you already found out,

$P(A)=\frac{2}{6}=\frac{1}{3} \\
P(S)=\frac{3}{6}=\frac{1}{2}$

**(c)** If they are independent, then $P(A\cap S) = P(A)\times P(S)$, let's see it that's true:

$P(A\cap S)=\frac{1}{6} \\
P(A) \times P(S) = \frac{1}{3}\times \frac{1}{2} = \frac{1}{6}$

So yes, they are independent.

**(d)** Using the same reasoning,

$$B: the\ chosen\ card\ is\ a\ 2 \\
T: the\ chosen\ card\ is\ a\ heart$$

$P(B\cap T) = P(B)\times P(T)$ since,
$\frac{1}{6} = \frac{1}{2}\times \frac{1}{3}$

EDIT (to make some clarifications regarding probability):

In case of independence:

> $P(A\cup B) = P(A)+P(B)\\
> P(A\cap B) = P(A)\times P(B)\\
> P(A\mid B) = P(A)$

In case of not being A and B independent events:

> $P(A\cup B) = P(A)+P(B)-P(A\cap B)\\
> P(A\cap B) = P(A)\times P(B\mid A)\\
> P(A\mid B) = \frac{P(A\cap B)}{P(B)}$

Comment: Thanks, I thought for an event like this you use this type of formula: $P(A |B) =\frac{ P(A ∩ B)}{P(B)}$

Comment: @Csci319 be more specific about your doubt. There are 4 questions being answered there.

Comment: I thought question $b$ was a conditional probability problem. I did not realize you just solve $P(A)$ and $P(S)$ separately

Comment: I think for what you did for $d$ is what I am thinking you do for $b$

Comment: @Csci319 note that you can prove independence through either $P(A\cap S)$, $P(A\cup B)$ or $P(A\mid S)$. I decided to use $P(A\cap S)$ because I found it was the easiest one given the available information.

Comment: $P(A|B)=\frac{P(A∩B)}{P(B)}$ is that equal to $\frac{\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{2}}{\frac{1}{2}}$? is how you do the calculation of conditional events?